# convert string into date in spark dataframe using spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i'm very new to spark world . im using spark version 2.3.1. i try to convert string  into date format in dataframe i.e "DD-MM-YYYY", however i googled and tried using cast,to_date function its not working . i don't know why .

this is my schema :

```
 b.printSchema
root
 |-- Emp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Doj: string (nullable = true)
```

My data in dataframe:

```
b.select($"Emp",$"Doj").show()
+---+----------+
|Emp|       Doj|
+---+----------+
|  a|20-08-2013|
|  b|24-05-1945|
|  c|13-07-2007|
+---+----------+
```

what i tried

```
b.select($"Emp",$"Doj".cast("date")).show()
+---+----+
|Emp| Doj|
+---+----+
|  a|null|
|  b|null|
|  c|null|
+---+----+



b.select($"Emp",to_date($"Doj","format")).show()
+---+------------------------+
|Emp|to_date(`Doj`, 'format')|
+---+------------------------+
|  a|                    null|
|  b|                    null|
|  c|                    null|
+---+------------------------+
```

why im getting only nulls???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting date from string to date in sparksql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52224651/converting-date-from-string-to-date-in-sparksql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why im getting only nulls???

Here

```
b.select($"Emp",$"Doj".cast("date")).show()
```

because data is not in a ISO 8601 compatible format.

Here

```
b.select($"Emp",to_date($"Doj","format")).show()
```

because "format" is well, not a format.

Use

```
b.select($"Emp",to_date($"Doj", "dd-MM-yyyy")).show()
```