# Converting date from string to date in sparksql

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a sparksql dateframe with dates in the following format: "26MAR2015".
In following question they use the *to_date* function with java simpledataformat: [Convert date from String to Date format in Dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40763796/convert-date-from-string-to-date-format-in-dataframes) to convert the strings in date. I could not find more information about this format in following question: [Convert pyspark string to date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080748/convert-pyspark-string-to-date-format).

I do not find the correct format for my case:

```
spark.sql("""
SELECT TO_DATE(CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('15MAR2015', '??????') AS TIMESTAMP)) AS newdate"""
).show()
```

Comment: Use `ddMMMyyyy` and then this is a possible duplicate of [Convert pyspark string to date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080748/convert-pyspark-string-to-date-format)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `ddMMMyyyy` as the format string.

For example, you could do:

```python
spark.sql("""
SELECT CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('15MAR2015', 'ddMMMyyyy')) AS date) AS newdate"""
).show()
#+----------+
#|   newdate|
#+----------+
#|2015-03-15|
#+----------+
```

You can find more information about the Java `SimpleDateFormat` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).